# I have found some error in my php script file & its about facebook data storage with php script

Tags: php, jquery

My Code is showed below:

```
session_start();
require_once __DIR__ . '\Facebook.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'App ID',
  'app_secret' => 'App Secreat',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
  ]);
```

The problem is :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Facebook.php on line 4
```

How can i define Class Facebook?

Comment: Can you show content of 'Facebook.php' ? At least first lines with namespaces and class name

Comment: This is class name & namespaces of my code:                                                                                                                  namespace Facebook;                                                                                            class Facebook
{
    /**
     * @const string Version number of the Facebook PHP SDK.
     */
    const VERSION = '5.0.0';

Comment: You missed "use" operator. Read official PHP documentation ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)) for more info

Comment: Or you may create new object from global namespace adding backslash before namespace like this: `$fb = new \Facebook\Facebook`

Comment: Thank u for your feedback. I have done it.